# Get ARN string from s3Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How would I be able to get [Arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) String from a [s3object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3Object.html)

I could probably do this myself, but want to use if some methods already exists to do this.

Comment: No methods that I'm aware of. You should DIY.

Comment: The s3Object Class doesn't any *Arn* property, but you can easily form it. The s3 arn syntax is **arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/key_name**. It doesn't require account number or region. Get the ***BucketName*** and ***Key*** property from the S3Object Class and form the arn by appending it to **arn:aws:s3:::** yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An ARN for an Amazon S3 object is in the form:

```
arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/filename-including-path
```

For example:

```
arn:aws:s3:::acme-inc/staff_photos/bob.jpg
```

The generic format for an ARN is:

```
arn:aws:SERVICE-NAME:REGION:ACCOUNT:RESOURCE
```

Given the name of an Amazon S3 bucket (which is globally unique), the system can determine the Region and Account, so those fields can be left blank when referring to an S3 bucket/object.